# Room 13 (SPECIFIC SENARIO) - How to face multiple attackers simultaneously

Tags: self-defense, streetfight

**Note: This question is based on a very specific senario, therefore not a duplicate of any questions currently on site.**

Some brief background: Over a decade ago there were an illegal organization using Electroconvulsive Therapy without anesthesia and muscle relaxant to "cure" internet addicts (mostly teens) in China. Long story short, you enter a room (Room 13) and...suffer things worse than death. The culprit is still at large and have attained polictical status since 2018. This question seeks to recreate and deal with the situation people face in Room 13.

The actual situation:

Place: A normal hospital room with a bed and a **electro pulse stimulator** (primary tool of torture). There is (assumed) no windows and one locked door that will take at least a kick to break down.

Opponents: 7~8 teens, mostly underfed, possibly with PTSD / Paranoia due to the suffering, assuming that less than 3 people have a martial arts background, but will simultaneously try to take you down and press you on the bed at all costs. You have the option of fighting with your back against 1~2 walls at once to decrease the total number of attackers coming at you at once.

Primary objective: To escape through the door or hold an important adult (head of conspiracy) as hostage. Killing him would also be an option since it is legally justified under the circumstances, but will possibly lessen chances of escape.

Secondary objective: To gather information and evidence useful in legal prosecution of the adult above, only possible when all opponents are incapacitated.

Are there any tactics to maximize success of reaching the primary objective? What fighting strategy should one use in this situation?

One last note: Your life will be at risk by that time since the electric current would be beyond safety limits, so legal consequences could be considered later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll pretend you're asking "tips for fighting multiple people at once?".
99% of it would be to avoid going to rough bars where something like this would happen; but if you do, recognize the situation and avoid it; or if you can't, apologize and grovel your way out of it; but if you can't, run; but if your avenue of escape is cut off...

You have to keep moving, to present a moving target, and if there's room to line up your opponents so that only one can attack you at a time. Strike first, strike hard, no mercy. Use any hard objects at hand. (But if you make them mad they'll maim you the way you tried to maim them.)
But nobody in the world is Donnie Yen IRL, so good luck, heh.

Comment: This answer has everything! It's helpful, it's easy to understand, and has a karate kid reference!

Comment: With the last item being the most important! :D